# How can I group rows with the same value from mySQL into php?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my mySQL table `animals`:

```
    ╔══════════╦══════╗
    ║  animal  ║ name ║
    ╠══════════╬══════╣
    ║   dog    ║ sam  ║
    ║   cat    ║ fred ║
    ║   cat    ║ todd ║
    ║  bird    ║ alan ║
    ╚══════════╩══════╝
```

I want to select all data into a table:

```
            $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals';
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo '<td>'.$row['animal'].' </td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['name'].' </td>';
            }
```

My result is:

```
    ╔══════════╦══════╗
    ║   dog    ║ sam  ║
    ║   cat    ║ fred ║
    ║   cat    ║ todd ║
    ║  bird    ║ alan ║
    ╚══════════╩══════╝
```

But I want to output rows with the same animal only once, but with all the names in one row, like this:

```
    ╔══════════╦═════════════╗
    ║   dog    ║ sam         ║
    ║   cat    ║ fred, todd  ║
    ║  bird    ║ alan        ║
    ╚══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. I try to think in this direction:

```
SELECT  *  FROM animals GROUP BY animal
```

But I am stuck! I am happy for every hint!

Comment: check my updated answer please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL has a non-standard SQL function called [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) specifically to do this.

Use as:

```
SELECT  animal, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as grouped_name  FROM animals GROUP BY animal
```

Use in PHP:

```
 $sql = ' SELECT  animal, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as grouped_name  FROM animals GROUP BY animal';
 foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
     echo '<td>'.$row['animal'].' </td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['grouped_name'].' </td>'; 
 }
```

Note how the column with the group is renamed/aliased to `grouped_name` this is because that column is not the `name` column anymore. You can refer to this column by its alias `grouped_name` in your sql result.

Comment: Thank you, I just tested your code, but I get a strange result. Shell I post it in my question?

Comment: What sort of strange result?

Comment: No, I made a mistake, whait a minute

Comment: No, everything is fine now!!

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT  
  a.animal
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) names
FROM animals a
GROUP BY a.animal
```

**Note** check my changed query and change your php fragment `$row['name']`  to `$row['names']`

**Update** change your loop to:

```
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$row['animal'].' </td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['names'].' </td></tr>';
        }
```

Comment: just because some people does not like it :-)

Comment: I suspect something else, but what ever.

Comment: I'm not the one with those downvotes but it seems @Alex might be among the user with almost 11K reputation and answering a question without any details

Comment: @Uchiha exactly, you are not among those strange people. I see no point to downvote even if there is no much explanation, but solution is working. so people could just upvote "best" answer. And I think that is how SO mostly works.

Comment: @Alex I'm just assuming one of those scenarios, I'm not sure about it as I've been already targeted for the same

Answer (score 4):

You can acheive it using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) AND [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

**GROUP BY** is used in conjunction with aggregate functions to group the result by one or more columns.

**GROUP_CONCAT** is a aggregate function used to concatenate the columns which is being grouped.

---

So in your case you should **GROUP BY** `animal` column and apply **GROUP_CONCAT** on the same. Like this:

```
SELECT  
  A.animal
  GROUP_CONCAT(A.name)
FROM animals A
GROUP BY A.animal
```

Comment: If you have used GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function like we've mentioned, it should work.